# How many ship were in the 'Conquest Fleet' in the Worldwar series

Tags: harry-turtledove, worldwar-series

In the Worldwar series ***how many ships*** were in the Conquest fleet?
Reading the books you can see names like; "[127th Emperor Hetto](http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/127th_Emperor_Hetto)".

Is this ship number #127 or the ship was named after the 127th Emperor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no in-canon description of the size or disposition of the Conquest Fleet. There's a mention that the '[colonisation fleet](http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/Colonization_Fleet)' numbers some 50-100 million individuals on what appear to be several hundred large ships (12 are destroyed on arrival) and that the conquest fleet is substantially smaller than the colonisation fleet.

In 'Upsetting the Balance' there's a scene where all of the Conquest Fleet's *shiplords* (captains?) meet in the Hetto's "great hall" to vote on the competence of the Fleetlord. Without an estimate of size, we can't be certain on numbers but it seems unlikely that something described as a [hall](http://www.c-h-w.com/venue/large-rooms/great-hall/) could contain more than one or two thousand individuals which at least gives us an approximate upper limit on numbers of ships.

---

As regards the *naming principles*, we see that Kirel (of the Race) refers to Pope Pius VII by his number, **then** by his name.

From this we can reasonably infer that the ship "127th Emperor Hetto" is named after the 127th Emperor to use that name rather than being the 127th ship to bear the name of the Emperor Hetto.

> “The loss of Rome was a heavy one for us in many ways, Exalted
>   Fleetlord,” Kirel agreed. “Not only were military and administrative
>   casualties heavy, the bomb also destroyed the Big Ugly who called
>   himself **12th Pope Pius**, and that male had been a leading factor in
>   accommodating the large number of Tosevites of his theological
>   persuasion to our rule. His traditional authority reached back almost
>   two thousand Tosevite years, which for this planet gives most antique
>   status.” <sub><sup>[Upsetting the Balance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldwar:_Upsetting_the_Balance)</sup></sub>

Comment: Notes: One gets the impression that the invasion fleet consisted of dozens of capital ships at most (though these are huge). They lose one of their large tank carrier aircrafts early on (analog of the C5 Galaxy?), of which they only have two in Europe which worries the Race... if they lose the other, they'd have to use starships for that purpose. Since the starships aren't going anywhere, why worry about those if you have 500? I doubt they had 50 of them total.

Comment: @JohnO - They seem to take the loss of each ship very badly. I think the implication is that it's a "face" thing. Losing even a single ship implies a catastrophic failure of command.

Comment: But they are also professionals, and losing a starship to do what by all accounts at that point would be a heroic undertaking would just be the cost of doing business. It seems more than them just taking it personally, more like it would be reckless/wreckful gambling to even consider such a thing. I don't believe there were many ships at all.

Comment: @JohnO - Professionals?! The Race seem wildly risk-averse as a species and utterly unwilling to do what needs to be done to subdue the Humans. Their plan basically boils down to continually giving us technology and then panicking.